# Make PostgreSQL listen to Google Data Studio

Tags: postgresql, looker-studio

I'm trying to connect one of my databases to Google Data Studio but I keep getting the following error:

```
Unable to reach the host.
```

I read the help page and already added the necessary IP addresses to the pg_hba.conf file this way:

```
hostnossl    google_data_studio             all             216.239.32.0/19         md5
```

That is just an example, but I have added all IP addresses required for the connection, 12 in total.

The connection description in Google's help pages shows these connections are non SSL (That's why I set it to hostnossl)

I've also restarted the postgresql service.

Answer (score 0):

"Unable to reach the host" is a Google Data Studio error message, not a PostgreSQL message.  PostgreSQL settings are irrelevant at this point.  You are not reaching the server at all.
Since this just became a networking and settings issue for Google, I'm voting to close.